# Array key value get in html from controller in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting array of key in angular js controller. And I am able to get particular value in controller. But I am not able to get in view(HTML).

**Controller:**

```
var statusLength= res.fsus.length;  
for(var i=0; i<statusLength; i++)
{    
       $scope.opts=res.fsus[i].statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode

}
```

In this loop I am able to get particular value. I want to display these value in View(HTML) part. I am new in angular js. I am not sure I am doing right or not.

**Value is In Loop**

**var

 car

 ban**

But when I tried to get in UI(HTML) then It will displaying only v a r. Not displaying var car ban. It is displaying only **v a r**

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat=" opt in opts">
       <span class="step">{{opt}}</span> 
</li>
```

**JSON**

```
fsus[{
  statusMessageType:{
       MasterConsignment:{
           ReportedStatus:{
             ReasonCode:"var"
             }
           }
       },
    statusMessageType:{
       MasterConsignment:{
           ReportedStatus:{
             ReasonCode:"car"
             }
           }
       },
   statusMessageType:{
       MasterConsignment:{
           ReportedStatus:{
             ReasonCode:"ban"
             }
           }
       },
}]
```

please share your idea. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON is not a valid one, change it as,

> [   {
>       "statusMessageType": {
>         "MasterConsignment": {
>           "ReportedStatus": {
>             "ReasonCode": "var"
>           }
>         }
>       }   },   {
>       "statusMessageType": {
>         "MasterConsignment": {
>           "ReportedStatus": {
>             "ReasonCode": "car"
>           }
>         }
>       }   },   {
>       "statusMessageType": {
>         "MasterConsignment": {
>           "ReportedStatus": {
>             "ReasonCode": "ban"
>           }
>         }
>       }   } ]

You can use ng-repeat with track by $index to display the options

```
<li ng-repeat="test in res.fsus track by $index">
      <span class="step">    {{test.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode}}
      </span> 
</li>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.res ={};
   $scope.res.fsus = [
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "var"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "ban"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="test in res.fsus track by $index">
  <span class="step">    {{test.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode}}
  </span> 
</li>
</body>
```

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: Yes. thanks for the help. But I want to get also another field. Right now i am bale to get. But Field is date like 2017-10-01T02:00:00.000Z. I want to convert into. YYYY-DD-MM@ HH:MM. could we convert with your approach?

Comment: you can use moment.js or angular-moment library to convert.

Comment: Yes I am using moment js. But I am new in this. Could you send me syntax with your code

Comment: need the corresponding json

Comment: I am getting OccurrenceDateTimeISO: "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z" key and value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153520/discussion-between-v-sh-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Could you see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013497/how-to-remove-duplicate-value-of-key-in-angular-js-ng-repeat

Comment: Could look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022270/datatable-is-not-generated-after-ng-click-in-angular-js/46022575#46022575

Answer (score 0):

What you have looped in the template is wrong:

You should loop the `fsus` values then display `ReasonCode`:

```
// Put fsus in $scope
$scope.fsus = res.fsus;
```

Then in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="statusMessageType in fsus">
  <span class="step">
    {{statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode}}
  </span> 
</li>
```

hope that helps.