# How to remove duplicate value of key in angular js ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat for array json value. But I want to remove duplicate value from UI(HTML).
Like Car value is repeating, So I want to remove duplicate key value. It should be come one time.

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.res ={};
   $scope.res.fsus = [
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "var"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "ban"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="test in res.fsus track by $index">
  <span class="step">    {{test.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode}}
  </span> 
</li>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use any external library, simply use angular.forEach to remove the repeated elements,

```
angular.forEach($scope.res.fsus,function(key,value){
  if(($scope.opts.indexOf(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode , 0)) <= -1){    $scope.opts.push(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode);
  };
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.res ={};
   $scope.res.fsus = [
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "var"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "ban"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

$scope.opts = [];
angular.forEach($scope.res.fsus,function(key,value){
  if(($scope.opts.indexOf(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode , 0)) <= -1){    $scope.opts.push(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode);
  };
});
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="test in opts">
  <span class="step">    {{test}}
  </span> 
</li>
</body>
```

Comment: I am trying this one. But It is giving me fsus undefined.

Comment: you need to put $scope.res.fsus, check the demo

Comment: I putted. But I don't know. Why it is comming.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Why it is giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'fsus' of undefined

Comment: @Sajeestharan. When I removing $scope. from fsus then it is working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153524/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-v-sh).

Answer (score 0):

You can use, lodash `_.uniqWith` along with `_.isEqual` to remove the equal object from the collection of objects. Read more about [lodash uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqWith).

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.res ={};
  fake = ['var', 'car', 'car', 'ban', 'car']
  $scope.res.fsus = fake.map( val => {
    return {
      "statusMessageType": {
        "MasterConsignment": {
          "ReportedStatus": {
            "ReasonCode": val
          }
        }
      }
    };
  })
  $scope.res.fsus = _.uniqWith($scope.res.fsus, _.isEqual);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="test in res.fsus track by $index">
    <span class="step">
      {{ test.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode }}
    </span> 
  </li>
</body>
```

**Note:** Maybe @Sajeetharan is right to use native code rather than external lib code, but if you are already using lodash in rest of your project(like me), you should stick with lodash for this one also.

Comment: But In your code. You are not using loadash. only you imported.

Comment: @VSH, please see the second last line of the js code above, `$scope.res.fsus = _.uniqWith($scope.res.fsus, _.isEqual);`

Comment: @VSH, please see my updated code, i have trimmed it.